# Can't leave beta test program for an app in the Play Store

Tags: google-play-store

A few months ago, I signed up to beta test the New Scientist app in the Google Play Store. Now, I would like to go back to using the production app. I went into Google Play Store and searched for the app, then under "you are a beta tester" I tapped on "leave". I then uninstalled the beta version.

The problem is, now when I search for New Scientist in the Google Play Store so that I can install the production version, it still only shows me the beta version, and it says "removing your account from the beta program." I can't reinstall the beta, and I can't install the production version, so I am stuck.

[image]

I have tried rebooting the device, and I thought about maybe deleting cache and storage for the app, but of course, the app is no longer on my phone, so I can't do that.

How can I go back to the production version?

Comment: Try clearing cache of Play Store app

Comment: If that doesn't fix, try uninstalling updates of Play Store and update Store

Comment: Could you check the app on the web version of the Play Store and see if there's any difference? Or check the beta tester again directly with [this link](https://play.google.com/apps/testing/com.newscientist.mobile)? Also, might be caching on the server-side of the Play Store.

Comment: I have the same problem, I can't find any way of leaving the beta program for a specific app or of installing the production version.

Comment: BTW in my case it turned out that it was because I wasn't added *directly* to the beta program, but rather as part of a group.  I had to log in to the play console using the beta program administrator credentials (which fortunately I had access to) to remove myself from the group. Even then the play store claimed I was a beta tester, but it correctly downloaded the prod version.

Answer (score 4):

Same problem with another application. Just go to   Settings → applications → Manage apps → Google Play Store → Storage → Clear data, and when it shows an option, choose only Cache.

Try to reach the app again.